# how to access downloaded file in IOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I've downloaded the file in IOS and successfully opened in the player in the current session of application in which it was downloaded. after downloading the file, my path was :

```
 file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2644B0D9-A68E-4A70-BAC3-2747949A980D/Documents/videoplayback.m4a
```

but when I close the application and try to use the same URL in the next session i.e. when the app is opened again, it just doesn't work. when I check the container it shows that the file is still there.

[image: App container screenshot]

Comment: try it by removing "file://" from the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every session is unique, you must get it like this

```
func url(for fileName: String, extension: String) -> URL? {
   guard let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return nil }
   return documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension(extension)
}
```

```
let url = url(for: "videoplayback", extension: "m4a")
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use most common approach, and that is using `UIDocumentInteractionController`
and `UIAlertController`

Check this part of code that is using popular `Alamofire` with progressview. Note if you are using this in your controller, it must implement fololowing delegate `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate`

Here is the full source code with download function:

```
class MyController: UIViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {

        var progressView: UIProgressView?    

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }               

        func downloadCommentFile(id: Int) {
            let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)  

            //MARK: Progress controller
            let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Downloading", message: "Downloading file", preferredStyle: .alert)
            alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil))

            //  Show UIAlertController it to your users
            present(alertView, animated: true, completion: {
                //  Add your progressbar after alert is shown (and measured)
                let margin:CGFloat = 8.0
                let rect = CGRect(x: margin, y: 72.0, width: alertView.view.frame.width - margin * 2.0 , height: 10.0)
                self.progressView = UIProgressView(frame: rect)
                self.progressView!.progress = 0
                self.progressView!.tintColor = self.view.tintColor
                alertView.view.addSubview(self.progressView!)
            })

            let url = "http://MyUrl/DownloadFile"
            let headers = ["Header1": "header 1 value"]

            Alamofire.download(url,
                method: .post,
                parameters: ["id": id],
                encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                headers: headers,
                to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
                    //progress closure                  
                    self.progressView?.setProgress(Float(progress.fractionCompleted), animated: true)
                }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
                    //here you able to access the DefaultDownloadResponse
                    //result closure
                    alertView.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
                        let viewer = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: DefaultDownloadResponse.destinationURL!)
                        viewer.delegate = self
                        viewer.presentPreview(animated: true)
                })
            })      
        }

        func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
            return self
        }

        private func documentInteractionControllerViewForPreview(controller: UIDocumentInteractionController!) -> UIView! {
            return self.view
        }

        func documentInteractionControllerRectForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> CGRect {
            return self.view.frame
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your time, but my question was related to something else and it's working fine now with the help of solution mentioned above. still thanks for your concern.

Comment: I saw that later :) have a nice day ;)